# EXCEL, I need to take data from 1 column & arrange in another column so the data loops

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

EXCEL, I have 4 columns. one column having part numbers, a blank column, column with group number & 123 count column.
 I need to take item 1 of the 1st group copy it to blank column but in the last position of the group & then move the 2nd item to the 1st position of the new column. item 3 would go to item 2 position in the new column & so on until the group was completed in the new column. 
I have thousands of these groups, needing help finding formula or creating a macro to arrange these so I don't have to do them manually.
Please help, Thank you CAD

Comment: People are having trouble understanding your question.  If my answer shows that I have misunderstood it, then [edit] the question to (1) explain more clearly what you want, ***AND*** (2) give an example.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have figured out how to do the sorting by color coating lines & converting a portion of the excel range to a table. Then sorting by group & colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your columns are `A`, `B`, `C`, …,
and that your data start in Row 2, put

```
=IF(C2=C3, A3, INDEX(A$2:A$20, MATCH(C2, C$2:C$20,0)))
```

(replacing `20` with the number of the last row that has data,
or a larger number) into cell `B2` and drag down.  This says,

- If the value in Column `C` on this row (`C2`)
  equals the value in Column `C` on the next row (`C3`),
  then this row and the next row are in the same group. 
  In that case,
  we want to take the value in Column `A` on the next row (`A3`)
  and shift it up into this row.
- Otherwise, *this* row is the last row of a group. 
  So, use the `MATCH()` function to find the first row of the current group
  (i.e., the first row whose `C` value equals the `C` value from this row, `C2`)
  and then use the `INDEX()` function to get the value in Column `A`
  from that row. 
  In other words, “take item 1 of the 1st group copy it to blank column
  but in the last position of the group”.

  [image]  [image: enlarged, with annotations]

Column `C` does not need to be sorted, but it does need to be *grouped*;
i.e., it fails if `C2`=`C12` but `C7` is different.